# Returning HTML through an ajax-call in Drupal 8

Tags: ajax, theming

I am trying to grasp the MVC/Symphony integraton of Drupal and am making use of the controllers. My controller has a function named "returnHTML" which is called by a normal XMLHttpRequest. Problem is I do not know how to generate the HTML. I could use a theme, but implementing a theme feels a little bit too complicated for this simple task. I want a HTML-fragment, ergo what you see is what you get, not a complete webpage.

Is there a way to return HTML just specifying where a twig is and have this twig-file injected with data in the "returnHTML"-function immediately? Also is there a recommended class (like Symphonys JsonResponse) which will help with the headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we are fairly new in the Drupal 8 jungle I'll give some feedback how I fixed this. Be aware this is probably not the best solution.

Using a controller I included this function:

```
    /**
     * Inspiration page action
     */
    function inspiration(){
        $twig = \Drupal::service('twig');
        $template = $twig->loadTemplate(drupal_get_path('module', 'experimental') . '/templates/inspiration.html.twig');
        echo $template->render([]);
        die;
    }
```

This works fine, allthough it is not very beautiful.

Comment: Worked for me almost 3 years later.  It would great to have a simple solution like this but with the "regular" render array with `'#theme'`. All my trials and errors (yes there's a LOT of that in Drupal) I wasn't able to render only the portion of what I needed. I always got the ENTIRE page, including the admin menus...

Comment: Ha found it: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231188/how-to-load-content-in-a-div-with-ajax which is a much nicer solution.

Comment: Hi, how you send variables to twig template? @Undrium